# Webmatrix - webimage crop then resize

Tags: image-processing, razor, webmatrix, webimage

I want to make sure that all the images that users upload to my website are the same size.

The size that I want to achieve is 620px x 405px

Because I don't want any white space in my images, and I want to keep the aspect ratio, I'm guessing I'll need to crop first, before I resize?

So far I've got the following code:

```
photo.Resize(width: 620, height:405, preserveAspectRatio: false, preventEnlarge: true);
```

But obviously this isn't giving me the desired affect.

I have seen other articles online where they do some formula, but I can't get any to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose someone uploads an image which is 1020 wide by 405? Which bit do you want to keep? The left hand end? Right hand end? The middle bit? Then the next image is 3000 x 3000. Now which bit do you want to crop? Perhaps this one needs resizing before cropping otherwise you might only get a window.

My recommendation is to allow the user to specify the crop area, and then you resize the resulting cropped image. There are a number of jQuery plugins that enable client side cropping. I've written about [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html) (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/161/WebMatrix-Testing-the-WebImage-Helper-With-JCrop) but I have also received some feedback that it is not reliable in some versions of IE (although I haven't tested that myself).